# How do I diagnose a failure of an installer generated by install4j on Windows?

Tags: install4j

If an installer generated by install4j does not work as expected, what steps should I follow to get diagnostic information?

Answer (score 0):

First,one has to find out at what stage the failure occurs. If you never see a window or only a very small window with a progress bar, it's a problem in the native launcher. In that case, you can get more information by executing

```
<installer>.exe /create-i4j-log
```

from the command line. This produces a log file and a message box will help to find the log file in the Windows explorer.

If the installer wizard is shown, there is a log file in the `%TEMP%` directory whose name starts with "i4j_log". The user can open the explorer, enter `%TEMP%` in the address bar and sort by modification date (descending). The topmost files should then include that log file.

If the installation completes and is non-functional, the log file is located in the `.install4j/installation.log` file in the installation directory.